# How to return from a widget to StreamBuilder after navigating to another page in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, stream-builder

So the first picture has codes from the first page where I have a StreamBuilder in my flutter app, there I tried navigating to the stateful widget named PickupScreen containing the code in second picture and it gave me an error which says SetState( or markNeedsbuild() called during build.So I called the widget directly and it worked but the problem is I cannot go the previous page I know I can't use pop but I need a solution for returning to previous page and show the else code.Currently I am Navigating to another page named HomePage.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it like that. Either you manage your screen state based on your `widget.channel.stream` or you must design your UI in a different way so you can actually `push` a new screen on your screen 1 and then you will be able to `pop`.

If you still want to keep it like that, you can do something like the following in your first screen:

```
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: widget.channel.stream,
  builder: (context, snapshot){
   if(snapshot.hasData && jsonDecode(snapshot.data['ntype'] == 10){
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => PickupScreen(data: jsonDecode(snapshot.data))));
    return const SizedBox();
 } else {
    return  _isLoading ? LoadingScreen() : Scaffold();
  }
});
```

Also, next time, make sure you copy/paste code instead of screenshots to make it easy to edit with modifications. :)

Comment: first of all sorry for the screenshots. secondly, wow it helped me to return but i have write repeated code like in the SizedBox you used, I had to replace that with the scaffold codes used below again .Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: Sure. Listen to your stream (eg. on your widgets `initState` and take action based on that if you want to push different screens) or don’t use navigators at all when using `StreamBuilder`.